# Join multiple databases with CouchDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchdb, document-database, couchdb-nano

**Tech being used:**

- Node.js
- Nano
- CouchDB

**Disclaimer:**

I am very new to CouchDB. I am able to query views with `Node.js` and `Nano` just fine. I am looking for more of a conceptual solution then a syntax solution.

**Scenario:**

I am building a very basic web app. I am attempting to get a baseball player from the database and place all his data into a `player/profile` page.

This player is going to belong to a team. The team has a short name and a long name.

Here are my databases:

```
{ name: "Derek Jeter", homeTown: "Brooklyn, New York", team_id: 10 } // player
{ shortName: "Yankees", longName: "NY Yankees", team_id: 10 } // team
```

I am trying to return a `JSON` object that looks like this:

```
{ name: "Derek Jeter", shortName: "Yankees" }
```

I know that I can include everything into a single database and use the `"type"` property to `emit()` based on the type, but I really don't want to do that.

**Question:**

How can I, using `Node` and `Nano` to query the player for `Derek Jeter` and `join` the other data from the other database? I know a view doesn't have access anything other then the current document that it resides, but there has to be another way?

I have searched multiple time on Stackoverflow and Google and I haven't found anyone straying away from the `"type"` solution.

Comment: If you're using node, your only real option is to query both databases and do your merge/join in memory. If you ever need to join across databases, you really really should consider combining the 2.

Comment: Hey @DominicBarnes, but aren't I forced to query twice anyway? How can I get the contents of `team_id` AND the player in ONE query?

Comment: There's actually a wonderful feature of CouchDB called "[Joined Documents](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/couchapp/views/joins.html?highlight=join)". The gist is, emit an object that looks like `{ _id: "related-doc-uuid" }` and when you use `include_docs=true` in your view query, it will pull *that document* instead of the original one.

Comment: And just to be clear, the "Joined Documents" feature **only** works on documents within the *same* database.

Comment: Thank you! Just out of curiosity, the tutorials I see for joins require the "related-doc-uuid" to correspond to the to-be-joined document's _id, can I match it to a property instead? (I have tried it and it doesn't seem to work)

Comment: Nope, only the `_id` can be used, it's the only way it can narrow down to a single document reliably and quickly.

Comment: Thanks again. Also, I really am having a tough time finding resources on CouchDB. I have tons of beginner questions that I can't seem to get answered. Do you have a tutorial do you give tutorials?

Comment: Their [core docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/) are really quite good, so I would start there.